# Type based on generic (function parameter's type)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to have a variable type based on function parameter type. I tried to use generics, but I still have some error.

```js
interface A {
    value: string;
}

interface B {
    value: number;
}

interface extA extends A {
    id?: string;
}

interface extB extends B {
    id?: number;
}

function foo<T extends A | B>(param: T) {
    const newParam: T extends A ? extA : extB = param;

    newParam.id = param.value;

    return newParam;
}


const a = { value: "1" } as A;
const b = { value: 1 } as B;

const resultA = foo(a); // resultA is "extA" not "extA | extB"
const resultB = foo(b); // resultB is "extB" not "extA | extB"
```

The code is made up, but it shows the idea. Based on the type of the function parameter `param` I want to use extended type of either of main types `newParam`. So if I choose a parameter of one of each type TS will know which type is being returned. How to achieve this?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QNzgBsBXCALmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8stRJZEUAhTHHkKkKyECQC2AI2jM2HcNHhJkEAB5h06yCAAmVNALzJgugPyUadEE1btOSnqo39tEPQf7Zjpi2MkyUHLsMCQgCGDAAPYgyDBRUQA8ACrOOvqGAD7IvAB8ABQADnBQcBKUyQCURngIMTRiEADuAAolZRVp7hnoZmnolNr8ALzIxaUSzIK4IM1tEwB0psij42ULwmRTxlAQYCRQsbOt7ZN27HUgDXArmATEZJQARACMT8gsyHAGqMyXDVJbhh7iJKC8Pl9PFN-mBkLsqCQiJpbvEovk4JVGMgAPTYuEQBFI9DAAxPbSod4gKKwskadDZIZPLAw-GEsAjOIJfJSTE4vHwxHskykxlianIWnIhkuJ5AA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need generics, then you can use function overloading in TS:

```
function foo(param: A): extA;
function foo(param: B): extB;
function foo(param: A | B): extA | extB {
    const newParam: extA | extB = param;
    newParam.id = param.value;

    return newParam;
}
```

[Full playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QNzgBsBXCALmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8stRJZEUAhTHHkKkKyECQC2AI2jM2HcNHhJkEAB5h06yCAAmVNALzJgugPyUadEE1btOSnqo39tEPQf7Zjpi2MkyUHLsMCQgCGDAAPYgyDBRUQAUAA5wUHASlKgAlJTaqMyh4ZExcQkpaRmUvLnOYLyFYRHRsfFJqemZhgA+yDV5Gui92l6CuAgxNGIQAO4ACpVd+cjDLsgAvMgdGczGILMLnQB0phtbi0fCZMxjyFAQYCRQsfvzi8FYEyBTcGcYBMQyJQAEQARmByBYyDgBgKn0mYGQUj+AJElFBkOhnhuXym9yoJCImjObUScGyjGQAHoqXcIASiehgAZgfkISAoojWYMVnVeMD4d9EfjCfUSeUpBTqbSRUT+MzkNz6uzOYrlqtlUA)

Type is correctly detected.

But you should watch yourself in the function implementation - you return `extA | extB` what can be not valid with previous overloads (developer can make mistake in implementation or add new overload and forget about implementation).
Example:

```
function foo(param: A): extA;
function foo(param: B): extB;
function foo(param: A | B): extA | extB {
    const newParam: extB = {
        value: 3,
        id: 22
    };

    return newParam; // always returned only `extB`
}

const a = { value: "1" } as A;
const b = { value: 1 } as B;

const resultA = foo(a);
const resultB = foo(b);

resultA.value // type detected as string
// (correct according to overloading) but implementation
// returns always number what is correct according to its definition
// but incorrect according to previous overload signatures - developer mistake
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+QNzgBsBXCALmQGcwpQBzAbiwF8stRJZEUAhTHHkKkKyECQC2AI2jM2HcNHhJkEAB5h06yCAAmVNALzJgugPyUadEE1btOSnqo39tEPQf7Zjpi2MkyUHLsMCQgCGDAAPYgyDBRUQAUAA5wUHASlKgAlJTaqMyh4ZExcQkpaRmUvLnOYLyFYRHRsfFJqemZhgA+yDV5Gui92l6CuAgxNGIQAO4ACpVdI8gAvEbGQsRklADMADRjG6aUAEwnhyzMh1AQYCRQsSCzC52MyAD078jEM3AAngYbncHhBdMgYkQ-sgAAYjaF2LATEBTOCrTAELaiABEAEYscgWN8DAVEZMwMgpGiMBiRJQcQSiX0rkipjcqCQiJo0W1EnBsswWeS2Rz6tzylJ+exhZzUAA6YRkD5fMB-ZIoXS3CARUGMqwMLCfZCJCZQG4Rb4IE26BjIMBRcH4aBEKJwa02bIUkjk4ASZJECASdxgOAlEAGr5A+7I75EX4A-zSaDIGYACxDJgMJrN5MQVptdpMYAMGpgoGAofDnu94Sipq1Octtbd9Ft9uSN3w0RIBiijqgztd1GA9BAIfuEAMAFpkBrHc61VBkBJgDQ4ABrCBAA)